# while running the dbt run command gets error

Tags: dbt

connection to dbt and snowfalke was successful but when tried to run this command:

```
$ dbt run
```

it gives this error

> ERROR: Runtime Error
> Could not find profile named 'learn_dbt'
> Encountered an error:
> Runtime Error
> Could not run dbt"

Am I making any command mistake?

Answer (score 15):

There are a few different approaches to solving to this problem:

1. Check the profile key in your `dbt_project.yml`
2. Check the profiles you have in your `profiles.yml`
3. Run `dbt debug --config-dir` to check where dbt thinks your config file is.

See the dbt documentation [here](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/guides/debugging-errors#could-not-find-profile)

Answer (score 5):

This is a problem in your profiles.yml file. You are running a project that requires you build a "dbt-learn" profile  to run.

[DBT profile.yml DOC](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/running-a-dbt-project/using-the-command-line-interface/configure-your-profile/)

Answer (score 1):

I think got the solution for this error if we give the dir name i,e dbt run --profiles-dir <path/of/.dbt folder>

Answer (score 0):

For these types of errors you must ensure that your

```
**profile: 'snowflake' # This setting configures which "profile" dbt uses for this project.**
```

matches the first key in **profile.yml** see https://docs.getdbt.com/dbt-cli/configure-your-profile

Answer (score -1):

For me the issue was that i didn't put all string profile parameters value(like host, user, pass...) inside a quotation marks. While there is an example in documentation when they are also omitted. So it was something like this

```
jaffle_shop:
  target: dev
  outputs:
    dev:
      type: postgres
      threads: 1
      host: localhost
      port: 5432
      user: postgres
      pass: example
      dbname: postgres
      schema: public
```

And it didn't work, but after i changed it to the following everything worked

```
jaffle_shop:
  outputs:
    dev:
      type: postgres
      threads: 1
      host: "localhost"
      port: 5432
      user: "postgres"
      pass: "example"
      dbname: "postgres"
      schema: "public"
```